# Question about priority of logical operators

Tags: javascript

The following code displays 3. Why? could you explain why?

```
alert( null || 2 && 3 || 4 );
```

Is there higher priority of && over || operator? why it doesn't display 2?

Comment: `&&` does have higher precedence, but that doesn't matter here; it would evaluate to `3` under any precedence rules. Can you explain how you think it could evaluate to `2`?

Comment: null is false and 2 is true

Comment: @Paulpro is right. `&&` evaluates to the right operand, never to the `2` on its left side. `2 && 3` and `2 && (3 || 4)` are `3`. Only `null || 2` alone would evaluate to `2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&&` operator precedence is higher than that of `||`. Thus  `null || 2 && 3 || 4` expression is effectively the same as  `null || (2 && 3) || 4`.

Let's evaluate the entire expression step by step:

1. `null` is a falsy value, so check the next operand
2. `(2 && 3)` results in 3 which is a truthy value, it stops here and returns 3

Answer (score 1):

The order of evaluation is

```
null || (2 && 3) || 4
null ||     3    || 4
      3          || 4
            3
```

[logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()) has a higher [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()).

```js
console.log(null || 2 && 3 || 4); // 3
```

Comment: Order of evaluation doesn't matter much here. It would log `3` no matter what order: `(null||2)&&(3||4)` or `(null||2) && 3 || 4` all evaluate to `3`

Answer (score 1):

> Is there higher priority of && over || operator?

Yes. This is called [operator precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations). You can find a [table for JS operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) at MDN.

Your expression is evaluated like

```
alert((null || (2 && 3)) || 4);
```

To get left-to-right evaluation, you will need to write

```
alert((null || 2) && 3 || 4 );
```

Comment: It still logs 3 and even if the precedence of `||` and `&&` were swapped it would still log 3.

Answer (score 0):

The `||` operator runs next operand if it returns **falsy** value.

The `&&` operator runs next operand if it returns **truthy** value.

Otherwise stop going further.

So,

```
- null || // false, go further
- 2 && // true, go further
- 3 || // true, stop
```

Thus, finally returns 3.

**Edit:**

If you talk about priority of the operator, then you may look at the [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). Where you can see `&&` operator has precedence value with 6 and `||` operator has precedence value with 5. So, `&&` operator has higher order.

Comment: Before the edit, there was no mention of operator precedence which is necessary to answer the question. After the edit, I don't think your explanation of precedence is good - it has nothing to do with reordering.